# How to turn off scientific notation for one column in numpy?

Tags: numpy

I am attempting to use scikit learn to classify some data. The data is stored in a .csv. My problem is that the instances are identified by unique 17-digit integers. When I load the data, python/numpy/scikit learn automatically converts to scientific notation and rounds the tail ends of the digits. How can I disable this feature for at least the variable that contains the ID numbers?

Also - I see that np.getfromtxt() has a 'dtype' option which allows the user to specify the datatype of each column. Is there a way to only use this option on one column? I have >250 columns, and it is not practical to individually specify the rest of the columns (which are all floats)

Here's my code for loading the data:

```
my_data = genfromtxt('data.csv', skip_header=1, delimiter=',')
data_list = my_data.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `dtype` used by `genfromtxt` is `np.float64`; that is, it tries to convert each field to a floating point value.  If you give the argument `dtype=None`, it will attempt to determine the data type of each field based on what it finds in the file.  That might work for you.

Here's an example.  The CSV file `stuff.csv` contains:

```
12345678901234567,1.2,3.4
13579246801234567,5.6,7.8
576460752303423488,0.1,2.3
```

which I'll dump to the console in ipython using `!cat stuff.csv`:

```
In [16]: !cat stuff.csv
12345678901234567,1.2,3.4
13579246801234567,5.6,7.8
576460752303423488,0.1,2.3
```

Read the file using `genfromtxt`, with `dtype=None`:

```
In [17]: data = genfromtxt('stuff.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)

In [18]: data
Out[18]: 
array([(12345678901234567, 1.2, 3.4), (13579246801234567, 5.6, 7.8),
       (576460752303423488, 0.1, 2.3)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8')])
```

`data` is a structured array, with three fields.  Field `f0` is a 64 bit integer, and the other fields are floating point.

If you convert this to a Python sequence using the `tolist()` method (as you do in the question), you get a list of tuples:

```
In [19]: data.tolist()
Out[19]: 
[(12345678901234567, 1.2, 3.4),
 (13579246801234567, 5.6, 7.8),
 (576460752303423488, 0.1, 2.3)]
```

*However*, that will not work if the native long integer is 32 bits.  Instead, you could try using a "converter" for the big integers.  That should let you convert them to whatever type you like (say, np.uint64 or even strings).

For example, this converts the long integer field to strings:

```
In [20]: genfromtxt('stuff.csv', dtype=None, delimiter=',', converters={0:lambda s: s})
Out[20]: 
array([('12345678901234567', 1.2, 3.4), ('13579246801234567', 5.6, 7.8),
       ('576460752303423488', 0.1, 2.3)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S18'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8')])
```

This converts them to 64 bit unsigned integers:

```
In [21]: genfromtxt('stuff.csv', dtype=None, delimiter=',', converters={0:lambda s: np.uint64(s)})
Out[21]: 
array([(12345678901234567L, 1.2, 3.4), (13579246801234567L, 5.6, 7.8),
       (576460752303423488L, 0.1, 2.3)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<u8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8')])
```

Comment: I don't think `None` will handle the OP's long integer case.

Comment: A 17 digit number will fit in a signed 64 bit integer.  It works for me, but the native integer size on my system is 64 bits.  I don't have a system where I can check what happens if the native integer is 32 bits.

Comment: `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`.  But you're right, you should have a few digits to spare on 64 bits.

Comment: @DSM:  Grrr...  Windows?  Does it help to add `converters={0:lambda s: np.int64(s)}`?

Comment: Linux with a 32-bit Python.  But using your converters trick to manually specify np.int64 does the trick!